# Is this stone natural or is it an ancient tool? (pictures from both sides)

Tags: ancient-history

[image][image]

[image]

So those are the two pictures I took. It kinda looks like a tiny axe but it could be natural. Can someone help me identify if this is an ancient artifact or just a natural rock with a special shape?

Comment: Can you precise the size of the artefact, and where you found it ?

Comment: I'm nowhere near an expert in this, but to my untrained eye, I'm not seeing much evidence of [knapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithic_reduction).

Comment: Sorry,I don’t remember where I found it. Its been a few years I have this stone

Comment: Without that site context (where) there is nothing History can do about providing the rest (Who, What When). Even the Earth Science stack gave up trying to identify rocks from photos. Nothing distinguishing enough from the photos to separate this from any other piece of [*leaverite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaverite).

Comment: ok thanks yall.

Comment: Another piece of information that might be useful is what that stone's made of. Some materials made much better tools than others, and our ancestors were definitely experts on the best stones to use. Again, I'm not great at ID'ing rocks, but that looks like shale to me? Shale cleaves flat super easy, which makes it great for [skipping stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_skipping), but I'd imagine not good for much else.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: So the general conclusion would be that this stone is natural.

Comment: @user65389 - I'd say *probably*, but I don't think anyone answering is an expert on this subject. We're much better on ... well ... history. I did find [a website on self-identification](https://peterborougharchaeology.org/archaeology-skills-techniques/identification-of-knapped-flints/) that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thx so much,this will help a lot.

Comment: Im not 100% sure but I think with all the info I have, it would be more probable that this is a natural stone. Maybe I am wrong tho

Comment: Maybe the question could go to earthscience. Some geologist are there.

Comment: ok I will try asking there

Comment: They should at least be able to identify what type of stone it is.

Comment: Can't "source" it, really, but this isn't a tool. It's a stone of a type that you could pick up from your neighbourhood train track; I've seen it's like countless times. It's too small and too irregularly shaped to really fit into the hand, and while it has some sharp(er) edges that could be *used* as a tool, it shows no signs of being *made* a tool. (E.g., you could pick up a stick and fend off a bear. Doesn't make the stick a tool or weapon. If you whittle down one end of the stick to a point and fire-harden it, *then* it becomes a weapon / tool.)

Comment: ok thx, that helps answering my question

Comment: Not to dispute @DevSolar , but there are known stone tools that are much smaller than this, and plenty in this size range - check out the image by [Mousterian tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_tool#Mode_III:_The_Mousterian_Industry) , but the key is that they *all*  show signs of being worked *and* are *all* from within a context be it tool making site or an inhabited cave or even a burial. Without these things it is unlikely to be a tool, but it is hard to say from from photos on the internet so people reserve their judgement.

Comment: @bob1 Well, I disagree with the degree of similarity between the tools displayed at your linked site and this here. This ain't an arrowhead or spearpoint, and certainly not a decorative item, ruling out most if not all of the possibilities in this sub-palm size range. {shrug} I just don't see how it could be serving any specific purpose other than "rock, black".

Comment: @DevSolar You said it was too small, so I was stating that there are plenty of stone tools in that size range and smaller, with a "but".  The "but" being that OP's object has *no similarities to known tools* given that it has no signs of working and no providence, which is what the rest of the comment was about.

Comment: @DevSolar Perhaps I should make that comment clearer - I was saying the only similarity was size; no other similarities that I can see.